# oracle data from one db to another db by using toad

Tags: sql, oracle

i need to take data from one db and need to insert the same in other db .
As of now i am using the toad

please guide me on this

Comment: Please ask this kind of questions on http://dba.stackexchange.com I know that is possible in more ways, but it depends on version and edition (eg. transportable tablespace may not be available on standard or express edition of oracle db)

Comment: @rkosegi from now onwards, i will use the dba.SE , but as of now can you guide on the same. its a easy thing,but i am new to this.regarding version and edition,it is same for both db.

Comment: Look here : http://www.toadworld.com/KNOWLEDGE/KnowledgeXpertforOracle/tabid/648/TopicID/CLHB/Default.aspx or google for oracle exp/imp or oracle datapump

Answer (score 1):

Create a DB LINK.. that will allow you to transport data accross databases.

CREATE DATABASE LINK: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_5005.htm